# Extract Text with the all styles applied from Word document in vsto word addin ribbon

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am working on extraction of Text from word in VSTO word addin and able to extract as well but I am only able to extract only text whatever text is there in the word document not the style which applied in the Word document. How can I extract text with all the style applied in the Word document.

Code reference which I am working on.

```
        Document document = new Document();
        var text = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Extract Text from Word and Save to StringBuilder Instance
        foreach (Section section in text.Sections)
        {
            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in section.Range.Paragraphs)
              {
                sb.AppendLine(paragraph.Range.Text);
              }
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\New folder\Extract.doc", sb.ToString());
            document.Close();
        }
```

Comment: How do you want to extract the styles or how should the result looks like? Should the output be XML or HTML or do you need only the name of the paragraph style?

Comment: suppose take example of resume from document  what ever look and feel available in word file same i want to extract it in pdf or any type of file.......In tha above code i am able to extract only text but not showing any header footer or any coloer i have applied to word document .... i want display that as well

Comment: To do what you wish to do you would need to open the second document and then work with the .formattedtext method of the paragraph range such that rangeintargetdoc.formattedtext=rangeinsourcedoc.formattedtext.

Comment: As i am newly using vsto not getting any Formattedtext property and throught string builder i an doing it as you can see in the above code

Comment: A stringbuilder only works with "plain text" - it cannot carry Word's formatting information. Word's formatting information is only relevant inside a Word document, in the context of the Word application. OR it would be necessary to work with Word Open XML, extracting the `Range.WordOpenXML`. But again, this content will only "show" formatting in another Word document. In order to use this in any other file format (PDF, for example) a converter is required. That's is definitely non-trivial.

Comment: Range.WordOpenXML where i can use in the above code?

Comment: sb.AppendLine(paragraph.Range.WordOpenXML)